# Where can I find the Credit default swap index that Chase bank puts out?

Tags: cds

Where can I find the Credit default swap index that JPMorganChase bank puts out?  I am able to find some indices for Europe but none for the US.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

That might be Markit CDX.NA.HY or CDX.NA.IG index, you can check them on [Markit website](http://www.markit.com/markit.jsp?jsppage=indices.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure [this pdf](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjl5u-zxpXTAhXjYZoKHU0yDf0QFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.markit.com%2FNewsInformation%2FNewsAnnouncementsFile%3FCMSID%3Df54b077c3a044773819dc8ccaf1afc6e&usg=AFQjCNEgmdk0rbdwA7K7_Igqo8w1L2H8QQ) will help you to understand what's lying beyond CDX.NA.IG and HY

As for the more info (from the link: @Alexander) iTraxx is product made by Deutsche Bank